# How to assign list value in a pandas df column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, indexing

I would like to create a new df column to hold list values.

```
def add_list_values(row): # row parameter is needed but not in this sample code
    list_val = [1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]
    return list_val

df['new_col'] = df.apply(add_list_values, axis=1)

Error: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (91, 4), indices imply (91, 2)
```

When I test by simply assigning a column with list value, I got similar error.

```
df['new_col2'] = [1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: What's your expected 'new_col2' column value? samples of a list [1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]? It seems that there's a mismatch in the number of rows according to the error.

Comment: `[1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]` has a length of 3, in your example the length of `df` appears to be longer than that.  To assign the list `[1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]` to every row in the `df` do something like `df['new_col2'] = [[1, 'OKOKOK', 2123] for x in df.index]`

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, try this instead of the line that gives you an error:

```
df['c']=[[1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]]*len(df)
df
Out[148]: 
   a  b                  c
0  1  1  [1, OKOKOK, 2123]
1  3  4  [1, OKOKOK, 2123]
2  3  4  [1, OKOKOK, 2123]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this can be applied to function used in df.apply?

Comment: // , I am assuming this code would replace the `df['new_col2'] = [1, 'OKOKOK', 2123]` in the original question?

Comment: I tried, but got this error - ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1